# How to remove duplicates from a dataframe based on the column with string values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicates based on the column `item_id` from a dataframe `df`.

`df` :

```
    date        code             item_id
0   20210325    30893       001 002 003 003 
1   20210325    10030       001 002 003 003
```

In this `df` the `item_id` is as follows:

```
These are all item_ids separated by one or more spaces.
    0 ->  "001  002 003 003"  #here there is an extra space after 001, rest is same.  
    1 ->  "001 002 003 003"
```

I am using the following function to remove the duplicates.

```
def create_data_file_removed_duplicate_item(packing_data):
    
    print('start removing duplicated item data')
    print('data count before removing duplication: ' + str(len(packing_data)))
    
    # check null
    packing_data = packing_data[~packing_data['item_id'].isnull()]
    
    # sorting item id
    packing_data['item_id_list'] = packing_data['item_id'].str.split('  ').apply(sorted)\
        .apply(lambda item_id_list: ''.join([item_id.replace(' ', '') + ' ' for item_id in item_id_list]))
   
    # drop duplicate item_id
    packing_data.drop_duplicates(keep='last', inplace=True, subset=['item_id_list'])
    packing_data = packing_data.drop(columns=['item_id_list'])

    # create non duplicate item data file
    print('data count after removing duplication: ' + str(len(packing_data)))
    
    return packing_data
```

I am unable to remove the duplicates although there rows `0` and `1` have similar `item_id`.
I have some other cases where this function removes duplicates where the `item_id` is as follows:

```
0 ->  "001 002 003 003".  # there is no space after 001. These are all item_ids separated by one or more spaces.
1 ->  "001 002 003 003"
```

`Expected output`:

```
     date        code            item_id
0   20210325    10030       001 002 003 003
```

Is there a way where I can remove the duplicates even if the `item_id` is separated by multiple spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a function to the column that will make the item_id "uniform", then can drop_duplicates()

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['20210325','20210325'],
                   'code':['30893','10030'],
                   'item_id':['001 002 003 003','001    002 003 003']})

df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x.split())).strip())
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='item_id', keep="last")
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
       date   code          item_id
1  20210325  10030  001 002 003 003
```

Comment: The original question had a sorting function. `packing_data['item_id'].str.split('  ').apply(sorted)\
        .apply(lambda item_id_list: ''.join([item_id.replace(' ', '') + ' ' for item_id in item_id_list]))` Is there a  way to use a sort

Comment: if `'item_id':['001 002 005 003 003', '001    002 003 003 005']})` How can we sort and these and still have the `uniform` item_id

Comment: @Sam, sorry didn't realize that part of it. I just updated it. It's a simple as a `sorted()` method to the split list.

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary column that removes the spaces, then drop duplicates based on that column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20210325, 20210325],
                   'code': [30893, 10030],
                   'item_id': ['001  002 003 003', '001 002 003 003']})


df = (df.assign(t=df['item_id'].str.replace(' ', ''))
        .drop_duplicates('t').drop(columns='t'))

print(df)
#       date   code           item_id
#0  20210325  30893  001  002 003 003
```